# How to find all possible words that can be created from a list of letters

Tags: objective-c, boggle

I have a list of letters and I'm trying to find all the possible words that can be created with those letters. I haven't found any implementations in objective-c or something close to it.

What I have found is a nice Boggle solver, which is good, but not what I want. I don't need the selected letters to be adjacent to each other. I want to find out how many words can be found by combining any letters in a 25 letter list.

Comment: Define "word". Is "ksjhdf" a word?

Comment: No, word is any word that can be found in an English dictionairy.

Comment: In that case you need a dictionary that can give you a list of *all possible words* or at least tell you all words that begin with a substring.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to read in a dictionary, and for each word, store an alphabetical list of letters the word contains. (If you're using ASCII, you can use a single 32-bit int to store the list for a given word. Just assign each letter of the alphabet a bit and turn it on if that letter exists in the word.)

Once you have the dictionary read in, you can scan through it to pull out words that contain the letters in your set of 25. If you followed the suggestion above to store the list of letters associated with each word in an int, you may get some false positives, where the word in question contains 2 of a letter, but you only had 1 letter in your list of 25. Discard those values.

The remaining set will be words that can be spelled using the 25 letters you have.